# Cannot retreive message via shared subscriptions with VerneMQ /MQTT

Tags: mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

**The problem**

I want to use shared subscriptions but cannot receive any messages when subscribing to shared topics.

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 1883 -q 2 -t \$share/group/audit/#
```

However, when subscibing to the topic without the share keyword, everything works fine

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 1883 -q 2 -t /audit/#
{"objectUuid":"3749003c-5302-4b1f-a111-4a42c5f08f14","trackingId":"155049F9-D8B7-467A-B775-5E9D82E94B26","system":"core","market":"Germany","user":"3749003c-5302-4b1f-a111-4a42c5f08f13","type":"Customer","action":"UNLOCKED","severity":"INFO","content":"testN480","createdAt":null}
```

**What I tried**

I already tried various versions of the topic name (with slash, without escaping the share keyword, without wildcard ...)

When looking at the topics on the broker instances (the mqtt broker is clustered) the subscription seem to be successful:

```
vernemq@mqtt-broker-1:~$ vmq-admin session show --topic
+----------------------------+
|           topic            |
+----------------------------+
|$share/audit-service/audit/#|
|          /audit/#          |
|$share/audit-service/audit/#|
|    $share/group/audit/#    |
+----------------------------+
```

The configuration looks like this

```
[{eleveldb,
     [{compression,true},
      {fadvise_willneed,false},
      {eleveldb_threads,71},
      {verify_compaction,true},
      {verify_checksums,true},
      {block_size_steps,16},
      {block_restart_interval,16},
      {sst_block_size,4096},
      {block_cache_threshold,33554432},
      {use_bloomfilter,true},
      {write_buffer_size_max,62914560},
      {write_buffer_size_min,31457280},
      {limited_developer_mem,false},
      {sync,false},
      {total_leveldb_mem_percent,70},
      {data_root,"./data/leveldb"},
      {data,[{dir,"./data"}]},
      {delete_threshold,1000},
      {tiered_slow_level,0}]},
 {riak_sysmon,
     [{busy_dist_port,true},
      {busy_port,true},
      {port_limit,2},
      {process_limit,30},
      {gc_ms_limit,0},
      {schedule_ms_limit,0},
      {heap_word_limit,20055500}]},
 {kernel,[{inet_dist_listen_max,9109},{inet_dist_listen_min,9100}]},
 {lager,
     [{error_logger_hwm,100},
      {error_logger_redirect,true},
      {crash_log_date,"$D0"},
      {crash_log_size,10485760},
      {crash_log_msg_size,65536},
      {handlers,
          [{lager_console_backend,debug},
           {lager_file_backend,
               [{file,"./log/error.log"},
                {level,error},
                {size,10485760},
                {date,"$D0"},
                {count,5}]}]},
      {crash_log,"./log/crash.log"},
      {crash_log_count,5}]},
 {sasl,[{sasl_error_logger,false}]},
 {vmq_swc,[{db_backend,leveldb},{data_dir,"./data/swc_meta"}]},
 {vmq_bridge,
     [{clique_lead_line,"    bridge      Manage MQTT bridges\n"},
      {registry_mfa,{vmq_reg,direct_plugin_exports,[vmq_bridge]}},
      {config,{[],[]}}]},
 {vmq_webhooks,
     [{pool_timeout,60000},
      {pool_max_connections,100},
      {clique_lead_line,"    webhooks    Manage webhooks\n"},
      {user_webhooks,[]}]},
 {vmq_diversity,
     [{clique_lead_line,"    script      Manage lua scripts\n"},
      {db_config,
          [{memcache,[{port,11211},{host,"localhost"}]},
           {redis,
               [{pool_size,5},
                {database,0},
                {password,[]},
                {port,6379},
                {host,"localhost"}]},
           {mongodb,
               [{w_mode,safe},
                {r_mode,master},
                {pool_size,5},
                {port,27017},
                {host,"localhost"}]},
           {mysql,
               [{password_hash_method,password},
                {pool_size,5},
                {database,"vernemq_db"},
                {password,"password"},
                {user,"root"},
                {port,3306},
                {host,"localhost"}]},
           {postgres,
               [{pool_size,5},
                {database,"vernemq_db"},
                {password,"password"},
                {user,"root"},
                {port,5432},
                {host,"localhost"}]}]},
      {auth_cache,
          [{redis,[{file,"./share/lua/auth/redis.lua"},{enabled,false}]},
           {mongodb,[{file,"./share/lua/auth/mongodb.lua"},{enabled,false}]},
           {mysql,[{file,"./share/lua/auth/mysql.lua"},{enabled,false}]},
           {postgres,
               [{file,"./share/lua/auth/postgres.lua"},{enabled,false}]}]},
      {script_dir,"./share/lua"},
      {nr_lua_states,1},
      {keep_state,false}]},
 {vmq_passwd,[{interval,10},{file,"./etc/vmq.passwd"}]},
 {vmq_acl,[{interval,10},{file,"./etc/vmq.acl"}]},
 {vmq_plugin,
     [{wait_for_proc,vmq_server_sup},
      {default_schema_dir,["/vernemq/lib/vmq_server-1.7.0/priv"]}]},
 {vmq_server,
     [{metadata_impl,vmq_plumtree},
      {receive_max_broker,65535},
      {receive_max_client,65535},
      {topic_alias_max_broker,0},
      {topic_alias_max_client,0},
      {suppress_lwt_on_session_takeover,false},
      {shared_subscription_timeout_action,ignore},
      {shared_subscription_policy,prefer_local},
      {msg_store_opts,[{store_dir,"./data/msgstore"}]},
      {graphite_include_labels,false},
      {graphite_api_key,[]},
      {graphite_prefix,[]},
      {graphite_reconnect_timeout,15000},
      {graphite_connect_timeout,5000},
      {graphite_interval,20000},
      {graphite_port,2003},
      {graphite_host,"localhost"},
      {graphite_enabled,false},
      {systree_reg_view,vmq_reg_trie},
      {systree_retain,false},
      {systree_qos,0},
      {systree_mountpoint,[]},
      {systree_interval,20000},
      {systree_enabled,true},
      {crl_refresh_interval,60000},
      {remote_enqueue_timeout,5000},
      {outgoing_clustering_buffer_size,10000},
      {upgrade_outgoing_qos,false},
      {max_message_size,0},
      {max_message_rate,0},
      {max_offline_messages,1000},
      {max_online_messages,1000},
      {max_inflight_messages,20},
      {max_client_id_size,100},
      {retry_interval,20},
      {default_reg_view,vmq_reg_trie},
      {queue_sup_sup_children,50},
      {max_msgs_per_drain_step,100},
      {max_drain_time,500},
      {allow_multiple_sessions,false},
      {allow_unsubscribe_during_netsplit,false},
      {allow_subscribe_during_netsplit,false},
      {allow_publish_during_netsplit,false},
      {allow_register_during_netsplit,false},
      {allow_anonymous,true},
      {queue_deliver_mode,fanout},
      {queue_type,fifo},
      {reg_views,[vmq_reg_trie]},
      {persistent_client_expiration,0},
      {max_last_will_delay,0},
      {message_size_limit,0},
      {http_modules,
          [vmq_metrics_http,vmq_http_mgmt_api,vmq_status_http,
           vmq_health_http]},
      {listeners,
          [{mqtt,
               [{{{0,0,0,0},1883},
                 [{max_connections,10000},
                  {nr_of_acceptors,10},
                  {mountpoint,[]},
                  {proxy_protocol,false},
                  {allowed_protocol_versions,[3,4,131]}]}]},
           {mqtts,[]},
           {mqttws,
               [{{{10,6,19,176},8080},
                 [{max_connections,10000},
                  {nr_of_acceptors,10},
                  {mountpoint,[]},
                  {proxy_protocol,false},
                  {allowed_protocol_versions,[3,4,131]}]}]},
           {mqttwss,[]},
           {vmq,
               [{{{10,6,19,176},44053},
                 [{max_connections,10000},
                  {nr_of_acceptors,10},
                  {mountpoint,[]}]}]},
           {vmqs,[]},
           {http,
               [{{{10,6,19,176},8888},
                 [{max_connections,10000},
                  {nr_of_acceptors,10},
                  {config_mod,vmq_http_config},
                  {config_fun,config},
                  {proxy_protocol,false}]},
                {{{127,0,0,1},8888},
                 [{max_connections,10000},
                  {nr_of_acceptors,10},
                  {config_mod,vmq_http_config},
                  {config_fun,config},
                  {proxy_protocol,false}]}]},
           {https,[]}]},
      {tcp_listen_options,
          [{nodelay,true},
           {linger,{true,0}},
           {send_timeout,30000},
           {send_timeout_close,true}]},
      {user_plugins,
          [{"vmq_acl",#{name => vmq_acl,path => undefined}},
           {"vmq_passwd",#{name => vmq_passwd,path => undefined}}]}]},
 {setup,[{data_dir,"./data/"},{log_dir,"./log/"}]},
 {plumtree,
     [{drop_i_have_threshold,1000000},
      {outstanding_limit,250000},
      {plumtree_data_dir,"./data/meta"}]}]
```

Is there any misconfiguration? Do I need to define any values in order to get shared subscriptions to work? 
Im using verneMq 1.7.0. The errorlog is empty. How can I debug why the messages are not send to the subscribers?

Comment: Can you verify how you publish? can you show the exact publish command? https://docs.vernemq.com/configuration/shared_subscriptions

Comment: I'm publishing like this `C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto_pub -h localhost -p 1883 -q 2 -t /audit/0001 -m "This is a test message"`

Comment: You're publishing to the wrong topic. Use `mosquitto_pub -h localhost -p 1883 -q 2 -t audit/0001 -m "This is a test message"` / or no / does matter.

Comment: Jesus O.o  ...  Thank you !